# Remove default docker registry and put prefix to pull images in Openshift 4.7

Tags: kubernetes, podman, openshift

I know we can add registry name before image name. like `docker pull my_registry/myimage:latest`. But by default it looks in docker hub. Is there anyway to remove docker hub from default or add a prefix for pulling image so if I try `docker pull redis`, it automatically runs `docker pull myrepo/redis` ?

I want to do it in openshift 4.7

[image]

As you see I want to look for `redis` in my private registry without adding `my_registry/redis`.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/registry/extended_registry_configuration.html#whitelisting-docker-registries)? Remember to use a proper fields names, like `[registries.search]` or `[registries.insecure]`.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to change the default registry name, you will introduce multiple security risks. https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/be-careful-when-pulling-images-short-name